# Структуры в JAVA?

Tags: java, структуры

Читаю книги и не понимаю, как реализовать структуры на JAVA как в C/С++.
В Cи все просто

```
struct dot{
int x;
int y
}

dot i; i[x] = 10; i[y] = 20;
```

Ну и можно сделать массив структур и там их сортировать как угодно. Как это реализуется в JAVA? Для меня было открытием что нету указателя &. Сейчас мне приходит в голову сделать отдельный класс под нужды структуры, но обращение и работа с классами съедает много времени и ресурсов.

Comment: В java нет ничего, кроме классов. А на счёт времени и ресурсов - вряд ли кто-то серьёзно рассчитывал обогнать c\c++.

Comment: В C/C++ не будет работать обращение к полю структуры через квадратные скобки. А в целом, делается класс с публичными полями, инициализируется переменная через `Dot i = new Dot();` и дальше можно обращаться к полям точно так же как в Си/С++ (через точку, естественно, а не через квадратные скобки)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Создайте класс. Можно с публичными полями, но лучше хотя бы с конструктором:

```
public class dot {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public dot(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Теперь вы можете объявить массив `dot[] dots = new dot[numberOfDots]` и присваивать элементы: `dots[0] = new dot(5, 6)`. Чтобы сортировать, используйте метод `Arrays.sort(dots, comparator)`. Например (Java-8):

```
Arrays.sort(dots, Comparator.comparingInt(dot -> dot.x).thenComparingInt(dot -> dot.y));
```

Отсортирует по возрастанию `x`, при равенстве `x` — по возрастанию `y`.

Да, массивы объектов в Java более тяжеловесны, чем массивы структур в Си. Но вполне закономерен вопрос, насколько это принципиально в вашем приложении. Не стоит оптимизировать преждевременно.

Comment: А по модулю вектора (x, y) как сравнить?

Comment: @banme, `Arrays.sort(dots, Comparator.comparingDouble(dot -> Math.hypot(dot.x, dot.y)))`.

Comment: Что-то не то с этими компараторами. Это же функции от двух переменных, а у Вас только одна. Разве не так должно быть: Arrays.sort(dots, (a, b) -> тут_нечто_с_a_и_b)?

Comment: @banme, методы вида `Comparator.comparingDouble` как раз превращают функцию одного переменного в функцию двух переменных. Вы, конечно, можете написать `(a, b) -> Double.compare(Math.hypot(a.x, a.y), Math.hypot(b.x, b.y))`, если вам так понятнее.

Comment: А на фига корень квадратный вычислять, если и без него всё будет ясно? Можно написать `dot -> dot.x*dot.x + dot.y*dot.y` ?

Comment: @banme, ну не вычисляйте :-) `Math.hypot` умный метод, он, к примеру, с переполнением бороться умеет (если dot.x и dot.y порядка 1E200, квадрат не влезет в double, а результат Math.hypot влезет) и с возможной потерей точности, если `x` и `y` сильно разные по порядку. Если вас эти мелочи не волнуют, смело выкидывайте.

Comment: Спасибо что прояснили ситуацию с компараторами. (хотя этот вопрос возник мимоходом). А главное что хотел узнать всё-таки offtopic. Узнаю потом как-нибудь.

Answer (score 2):

Самое лучшее, что могло бы вам прийти в голову - программировать на Java, как принято программировать на Java, а на С, как принято на С. У каждого языка свои инструменты реализации поставленных задач.

Не стоит пытаться притянуть за уши паттерны и структуры, практикуемые в других языках. В конце концов вы же не пытаетесь использовать английскую грамматику при построении предложений на русском языке, а если бы вы так делали, то выглядели бы весьма комично.

В Java достаточно собственных средств, паттернов и алгоритмов, чтобы решать самый широкий круг задач. Поверьте, множество Java-программистов прекрасно обходятся без указателей и структур и даже не жалеют о их отсутствии.

Если же вам без указателей не в моготу, то продолжайте писать на С\С++, но, пожалуйста, не придумывайте каких то костылей, чтобы превратить один язык в другой.